# CDC for multiple Consumers of same table where each consumer reads different set of Columns

Tags: database, oracle, apache-kafka, cdc

I have a table (let's say Employee) with around 130 Columns depicting different attributes/characteristics of an Employee record. Now I have multiple downstream systems who need data as file (batch process) which runs periodically (every 12 hrs or 1 day).

Each consumer is intrested in certain column values only and not the entire set of emoployee record. 
E.g. Consumer 1 : Needs Column 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 100, 121, 130
Consumer 2 : Needs 3, 4, 15, 125, 126

And so on. There are currently 10-12 different consumers who need different set of columns.

Intrestingly each consumber is intrested only in DELTA information which is based on columns which that consumer is intrested in.
E.g. So Consumer 1 should get get DELTA ONLY IF there are changes in Column 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 100, 121, 130.

Are there any CDC or any other tools which help us to achieve this requirement ?

PS : Following solutions were thought and being planned. Not sure which one to pick  :

Maintain previous-day (historic) data table for Employee and then use Minus ('-') operator in Oracle to capture difference. E.g. (Select Col 1, Col2, Col5, Col10.. from current-day-employee) - (Select Col 1, Col2, Col5, Col10.. from previous-day-employee).

This option was not considered because (1) data in current-day-employee table keeps on changing in real-time from source and (2) Will have to create table for each downstream consumer.

Please suggest a tool or solution.

Comment: Hello Ravish, let me know if my answer's the question "Are there any CDC or any other tools which help us to achieve this requirement ?".  I suspect I've outlined one way to satisfy it with our product, but do let me know on the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM IDR product has "KCOP" (Kafka Custom Operation Processor) feature.  It allows you to define any number of records to write to Kafka in response to a DML event.  Thus off a single CDC event you could write to different topics customized data for each application, which need only read its respective topic then.

In addition there are KCOP's which provide before and after values, you could thus programatically determine when to write out the record based on whether there was a change between the before and after columns of interest.  So Each resulting topic could then only contain an entry if there was an applicable column change in it.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdckafka.doc/concepts/kafkakcop.html

There are other potential means of achieving some of your objectives, but this is an example of one way the IBM product IDR, could meet your objective.